# Search Service Error

Tags: sharepoint, search, search-server

I'm getting the following error when I try to go into the "Content Sources" section of the Search Administrator in the SSP.

> The search service is currently offline. Visit the Services on Server page in SharePoint Central Administration to verify whether the service is enabled. This might also be because an indexer move is in progress.

I know that the service is started, and that the index is not being moved.

The *Crawl Status* is **Error**.

I have reconfigured the Search, and still I get the same error. The account running the service has the correct security settings on the SQL Server.

Comment: Definitley need more details on this, please check the event logs and SharePoint logs and post any relevant information.

Comment: Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance (88ef2e63-8897-4bff-8473-f1a19b5ad59b).

Reason: Object b2fb0953-2f86-4187-a9ae-602f9d65cb31 not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this I had to **create a new** SSP. Reconfigure it to match my all settings and place all my web applications on the new SSP. In addition, when creating the Crawl Schedule, I got the Access Denied issue and solved as suggested by Alex.

Answer (score 0):

The event log should have more and better information. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the search or indexing service (or both) has entered into an inconsistent state. Stop both the search and indexing service which should remove their files, then start them again. Your configuration should be kept, although you may wish to make a note of it just in case.

If you can provide any more details about the configuration of your farm, particularly which servers run each service, that would help. Also the service pack and/or cumulative update level you are patched to.

Comment: The server runs all roles WFE/Indexing/Query and the other is just a SQL 2005 DB. The Version currently running is 12.0.0.6318. I stopped and started the services as you suggested. However, it remains saying "Error" on the Crawl Status. What I did notice is that when I click on "Content Sources" it gives me a HTTP 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Now I'm getting "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040D1B" when I go to "Content Sources"

Comment: OK, I *can* help you with the 403. Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926959

Comment: I tried this, however I got the same error back.